# Wiping browser history with javascript (or preventing URL from being recorded)

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-history

I have a client (domestic violence center) who wants to know if we can prevent their site from showing up in browser history, or wipe the users visit from their browser history when they exit the site.

I know once someone is on the site we can build it in ways that prevent new pages from loading like a normal page using location.replace for navigation, but that initial page visit when someone typed in http://example.org will still be in the history.

Is it possible on page load to prevent the page from being recorded in the history, or erase the record if it exists?

I have a bad feeling it can't, but if anyone will know it's all my smartypants friends on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think raising public awareness for [incognito mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_mode) (supported by most major browsers) would be the appropriate solution. I don't think there's much that can be done from the web site's side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this can't be done.

For your clients scenario, my best advice would be that users are educated on how to remove their visit from their browser history, and how to use anonymous browsing/private mode/incognito mode in future visits.

Comment: That's what I was worried about. I was going to propose to the client having some sort of "safe browsing tips" page prominently called out - but any time I can have a machine do something rather than count on users to follow instructions... well, you know.

Comment: But it is possible to do this in a browser extension, using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) in Firefox or [chrome.history](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/history/) in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history#Notes):

> There is no way to clear the session history or to disable the
>   back/forward navigation from unprivileged code. The closest available
>   solution is the location.replace() method, which replaces the current
>   item of the session history with the provided URL.

So I think what your client wishes for is just not possible.

Comment: Thanks. I should have checked MDN, thanks for the reminder of that resource.

Answer (score 3):

Add script to recognise each browser, and provide browser specific steps to erase history/use incognito mode.

Comment: By specific steps I mean how-to's for users to clear their history

Answer (score -1):

A properly configured proxy server may be of use in that context.

Comment: I don't see how this would help.

Comment: A CGI proxy, running off an https link, will

a) Hide the URL that the user is visiting.
b) Such a proxy server can also send a "do no cache" header that the user-agent/browser should honor.

This way, it will fulfill both of the OP's requirements.

Something like http://hidemyass.com/ with the SSL switch turned on.

Comment: A nice cheese sandwich would be more useful.